# FullCalendar gotoDate loses drop event with multiple calendars

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

We are making a web application where users can create theire own calendars. They should be able to create multiple calendars (all in view agendaDay) on one page. There are external events that have to be dropped on the calendars to make appointments. Everything we want to do is working like a charm!

But we have 1 problem and we can't seem to get a solution for it.

We have a second (month) calendar (dynamicly created) and we are using this calendar to navigate between days. When a user clicks on a day we use gotoDate to change the FullCalendars day.

This is where the problem comes in. When we use gotoDate on all the calendars on the page it's not possible drop the external events on the first calendar. Dropping the events on de second or third calendar is not giving any problems.

What i have seen is that the fullCalendar gets destroyed in the renderView function in the fullcalendar.js on line 724 (version 2.2.6). After this the fullcalendar has been rendered again. 
When i uncomment the destroy the problem is solved but then ofcourse the drop event gets initialized for second time (or third, or fourth).

I'm unable to find a solution so trying to find some help for this.

See my code on: http://jsbin.com/pubelo/1/

I have also submitted this to the FullCalendar issue tracker but i'm trying to find a fast solution for now.

**Update 1**
Still looking into the FullCalendar.js code. I have noticed that the problem is solved when i remove line 6414 in the destroy function.

```
this.el.empty();
```

But removing that line results in double javascript events.

**Update 2**
Changed the jsbin link.

**Update 3**
I have noticed that the handler 'documentDragStart' isn't called on the first calendar when using the gotoDate.

**Update 4**
Problem turns out to be in "var Grid = fc.Grid = RowRenderer.extend({" unbindHandlers function.

Because the seconds calendar is calling the unbindHandler after the first calendar called the bindHandlers the dragstart has been removed and only applied once (to the last calendar).

Haven't found a solution tho...

**Workaround / solution**
Got a work around for the problem.

I'm destroying both calendars. After that i initialize both calendars again with defaultDate paramater set to the correct date.

This seems to work fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a work around for the problem.

I'm destroying both calendars. After that i initialize both calendars again with defaultDate paramater set to the correct date.

This seems to work fine for now.

**Update**
Problem had been fixed by Arshaw and released in the newest version 2.3.0.